# node.js, vue.js and express.js stack development

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

I am trying to create a web app using vue.js, express.js and node.js using the Visual Studio Code IDE on Linux. Following some documentation online, I have read that after installing vue.js, one can create a **vue.js app** using the following command:

```
vue create my-app
```

Following other documentation, it is stated that one can create an **express.js** app by executing this command:

```
express myExpressApp
```

How can I create an app, that I will be developing using the VS Code IDE that is **both** a vue.js app and an express.js app?

Comment: This is too broad, it depends what kind of application you're trying to build and how you intend to deploy it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend creating your vue app first. The add in the Express stuff manually, because that bit is quick and easy.

#### 1. Start by creating your vue app

If you follow the [vue documentation here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html), using the vue-cli it will structure everything for you

The contents of your vue source will live inside the `src` directory in your project root. Once you've run `npm run build` (same as `vue-cli-service build`) a `dist` directory will be created, containing the built client-side code.

#### 2. Add in Express

I'd recommend putting your server side code in a new directory in your project root, say `server`, then create a file in that dir, and add in the below code...

```
const express = require('express');
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
const path = require('path');

require('dotenv').config()

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Serve up built vue app, at the main root
const staticFileMiddleware = express.static(path.join('dist'));
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);
app.use(history({
  disableDotRule: true,
  verbose: true
}));
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);


// Make all public assets available 
app.use('/public', express.static('public'))

// App has started
app.listen(port, () => 
    console.log(`Awesome app has started and is running on port ${port} `)
);
```

There are a couple of dependencies you will need, for the above sample you'll have to `yarn add express connect-history-api-fallback dotenv` (or use npm).

- [`express`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) is obviously needed
- [`connect-history-api-fallback dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-history-api-fallback) is needed if your using history mode in vue, it is required to not get a 404 on every sub-page.
- And [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv), is just a nice-to-have to read constants from your `.env` file, which you should also create

Finally to run it, type `node server/main` (or whatever you called that file in your server dir).

You will probably want to add that command to your package.json..

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/main",
     ...
```

If your using Heroku, double check all your dependencies are correct in your `package.json`, then create a file called `Procfile` in your root, containing the following `web: node ./server/main.js` (or whatever your server file was called), and boom, your vue app is now an Express vue app, and ready for deploy!

Source: I've done this setup a lot of times for my own sites.